# Polars: How can I convert a Polars Dataframe to a Python list'

Tags: python, dataframe, series, python-polars

I understand Polars Series can be exported to a Python list. However, is there any way I can convert a Polars Dataframe to a Python list?

In addition, if there is a one single column in the Polars Dataframe, how can I convert that into a Polars Series?

I tried to use the pandas commands but it didn't work. I also checked the official Polars website to see any related built-in functions, but I didn't see any.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about the [`rows()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rows.html) method?

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 3, 5],
        "b": [2, 4, 6],
    }
)
```

```py
df.rows()
```

`[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`

```py
df.rows(named=True)
```

`[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]`

Alternatively, you could get all the DataFrame's columns using the [`get_columns()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.get_columns.html) method, which would give you a list of Series, which you can then convert into a list of lists using the [`to_list()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.to_list.html) method on each Series in the list.

If that's not what you're looking for be sure to hit me up with a reply, maybe then I'll be able to be of help to you.